# dropdown menu using HTML and CSS is giving me a headache

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

```
<div class="fbtop">
  <img src="https://static.solidshops.com/1441/files/Logo-site.png" title="Pieke Wieke" alt="Pieke Wieke">
  <h2 class="title">Zelfgemaakt met liefde</h2>


  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li>
  <a href="https://piekewieke-fb.solidshops.com/category/naaibenodigdheden">Naaibenodigdheden</a>

     <ul class="sub_menu">
            <li>
      <a href="https://piekewieke-fb.solidshops.com/category/naaibenodigdheden-allerlei">Allerlei</a>
              </li>
            <li>
          <a href="https://piekewieke-fb.solidshops.com/category/naaibenodigdheden-spelden">Spelden</a>
              </li>
            <li>
      <a href="https://piekewieke-fb.solidshops.com/category/naaibenodigdheden-naalden">Naalden</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </li>
    <li>
  <a href="/category/stoffen">Stoffen</a>

  <ul class="sub_menu">
            <li>
      <a href="/category/stoffen-effen">Effen</a>
              </li>
            <li>
      <a href="/category/stoffen-katoen">Katoen</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
          <a href="/category/stoffen-katoen-pieke-wieke-for-soft-cactus">Pieke Wieke for Soft Cactus</a>
        </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/category/stoffen-katoen-soft-cactus">Soft Cactus</a>
        </li>
                    <li>
          <a href="/category/stoffen-katoen-bedrukte-katoen">Bedrukte katoen</a>
        </li>
                    <li>
          <a href="/category/stoffen-katoen-basics">Basics</a>
        </li>
                    <li>
          <a href="/category/stoffen-katoen-stretchkatoen">Stretchkatoen</a>
        </li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
            <li>
      <a href="/category/stoffen-bedrukt">Bedrukt</a>
              </li>
            <li>
      <a href="/category/stoffen-stretch-katoen">Stretch katoen</a>
              </li>
            <li>
      <a href="/category/stoffen-tricot">Tricot</a>
              </li>
            <li>
      <a href="/category/stoffen-flannel">Flannel</a>
              </li>
            <li>
      <a href="/category/stoffen-gabardine">Gabardine</a>
              </li>
            <li>
      <a href="/category/stoffen-ribfluweel">Ribfluweel</a>
              </li>
            <li>
      <a href="/category/stoffen-voering">Voering</a>
              </li>
            <li>
      <a href="/category/stoffen-teddy-fleece">Teddy fleece</a>
              </li>
            <li>
      <a href="/category/stoffen-geweven">Geweven</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </li>
    <li>
  <a href="/category/flockfolie">Flockfolie</a>
      </li>
    <li>
  <a href="/category/workshops">Workshops</a>
      </li>
    <li>
  <a href="/category/waardebonnen">Waardebonnen</a>
      </li>
    <li>
  <a href="/category/vlieseline">Vlieseline</a>
      </li>
    <li>
  <a href="/category/fournituren">Fournituren</a>

  <ul class="sub_menu">
            <li>
      <a href="/category/fournituren-lint">Lint</a>
              </li>
            <li>
      <a href="/category/fournituren-garen">Garen</a>
              </li>
            <li>
      <a href="/category/fournituren-ritsen">Ritsen</a>
              </li>
            <li>
      <a href="/category/fournituren-paspel">Paspel</a>
              </li>
            <li>
      <a href="/category/fournituren-biais">Biais</a>
              </li>
            <li>
      <a href="/category/fournituren-elastiek">Elastiek</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

It's a classic way of doing dropdown menu's by css, to see it at work you can go to http://jsfiddle.net/W6Rhe/

There you'll also see the issue that I have with the menu. If you select the first item "Naaibenodigdheden" you'll see that the first sub menu item has front color white instead of red.

If you go to stoffen, you'll notice the same behaviour, if you select the sub menu "katoen" you'll notice the same behaviour again.

Now the cherry on the pie of this delicious issue is that when I adjust all my links to relative links (ie I remove https://blabla.blah.com) then All the items appear in red as intended.

What the hell am I doing wrong? I just don't get it.

ps tested this on chrome
ps2 it appears that when I replace the url in whatever is not what they are now, the problem does not occur, bizar is my only term for this behaviour

Comment: I'm not sure what your're talking about. Looks fine in the fiddle here. Tested in Chrome, Firefox, and IE. http://i.imgur.com/wLcQhVJ.png

Comment: front color or font color? the font color is red for me

Comment: mituw, try to click on a link, so that you have visited it and then check it out again (see answer below from Andy)

The white links that I get are because I have visited the link before, alas after visiting, I can't seem to override the 'visited' color (white) to my red

Comment: Since I can't edit my previous answer, mituw: here are some screenshots of the problem at work: http://imgur.com/oReiWHA,R0UtyoQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code here:

```
ul.dropdown li a:visited,
ul.dropdown li a:hover
{ 
    color:#fff;
}
```

is overriding the color on `:visited` links to white.

The reason the color changes when you use a relative URL is because the browser no longers sees it as visited, because it is a different path.

Comment: I tried to add your code to the css in jsFiddle and within the site itself, but alas, the solution does not remove the visited paths

Comment: @SSX-SL33PY Then it's probably a different line of code which is overriding the color. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the culprit, thanks to Andy for pointing me into the right direction:

```
ul.dropdown ul li a:hover,
ul.dropdown ul li a:active,
ul.dropdown ul li a:link             {color: #e10707; }
```

He noticed that the links that were still white were in fact links colored trough the :visited attribute that was declared #fff or white :)

There is one state missing in the previous code block, indeed the a:visited color is not set to red, that's why it was white